# Entity Framework the order sql generated by Savechanges()

Tags: entity-framework

I am looking at the sql executed when I call SaveChanges on context, it does update , delete and insert sql stament in that order.. is there a way to change it to delete , update , insert ?

Answer (score 2):

The only way that I can think of is to call your `Delete()` first then `SaveChanges()` then do the rest `Insert()` and `Update()`. Not saying that is the only way...

Looks like there is no way to change the order... - [DbContext SaveChanges Order of Statement Execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335582/dbcontext-savechanges-order-of-statement-execution)

Comment: This answer is correct. To add a little, SaveChanges generates an order based on constraints between different tables/rows such that the save would succeed. Often using a different order will fail with constraint violations, at least on SQL Server and many other databases.

Answer (score -4):

SaveChanges execute your changes in the same order that you added them to the datacontex.
Make sure that you add them in the right order or at least an order that allows them to be executed.

Comment: It's not guaranteed that changes will be done in the order you added

Comment: Definitely not true. Just tested that myself.